# Various linear regressions that activate in linear regression within the same model

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, interaction, coefficients

I want to create a linear regression of the next sort:

> $$Y=(1-\sigma)(\alpha_i + \beta_i x)+ \sigma(\alpha_j+\beta_j x)+\varepsilon$$

Where sigma refers to different time periods. I want to run it within the same `lm()` function.

I first tried to run different `lm()` models a code somewhat like this:

```
start_dates <- as.Date(c("2003-01-01", "2008-01-01", "2016-01-01","2020-03-01"))
end_dates <- as.Date(c("2007-12-01", "2015-12-01", "2020-02-01", "2023-03-01"))
for (i in 1:length(start_dates)) {
  subset_df <- df[df$date >= start_dates[i] & df$date <= end_dates[i], ]
  regression_results[[i]] <- lm(short ~ inf, data = subset_df)
  regr<-lm(short ~ inf, data = subset_df)
  assign(paste("m1", i, sep ="_"), regr)
}
```

This code ran perfectly, yet it did not quite do what I wanted it to do before, since coefficients are stored in different regression models. Also, the error term is different in all of them. I then tried running a code with dummies, something like this:

```
lm_prueba<-lm(short~inf:period1+inf:period2+inf:period3+inf:period4, data=data_dummies)
```

The problem is the interaction with dummies does not create different intercepts as I want, and dummies by itself switch the model. Is there anyway to do this?